# Negative feedback with only passive components?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator

1) Negative/positive feedback with only passive components, whether this makes sense at all?

Listing the book about signal processing i found [image: this page.]

Comment: The feedback loop itself, sure. But not the summer.

Comment: why not the summer?

Comment: Summer works fine, and just says that i=i1+i2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that you gain much understanding by looking at this as a feedback circuit, but the equations certainly work.  I suppose it make it real easy to see that as V goes to the point where i2=i, then i1 goes to zero.